# VS Code deploy: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: deployment, vs-code

I'm trying to deploy code in VS Code to an org.  I'm getting the following error.  The package.xml is valid, as far as I can tell.

```
Starting SFDX: Deploy Source to Org

14:57:24.268 sfdx force:source:deploy --manifest c:\projects\VS Code\User Budgets\manifest\package.xml --json --loglevel fatal
14:57:29.355 sfdx force:source:deploy --manifest c:\projects\VS Code\User Budgets\manifest\package.xml --json --loglevel fatal ended with exit code 1

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Any pointers on how to troubleshoot this?

UPDATE:
I resolved a few issues:

1. The name of one class didn't match the class' file name
2. The code in one Visualforce component was missing a  tag

I am able to create a package version now.  Deploying the code defined in the package.xml still does not work, however.

Comment: How large is your project (filesize of the directory, and number of components like classes, validation rules, pages, etc...)?

Comment: The size of the force-app/main/default folder is 6.96 KB (7,129 bytes)

Comment: What version of vscode and the salesforce vscode extension ?

Comment: Could be a bug in the CLI such as [this one](https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-core/issues/178). Are you running the latest version of the CLI?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava 47.10.0 - December 12, 2019

Comment: @MarkPond sfdx-cli/7.41.0-2a5f766389 win32-x64 node-v10.15.3

Comment: i also faced same issue today 'sfdx force:source:deploy -x manifest/package.xml
ERROR running force:source:deploy: Maximum call stack size exceeded' error.
i didn't add any custom labels in my package.xml still i am facing issue.
cli version : sfdx -v
sfdx-cli/7.41.0-2a5f766389 win32-x64 node-v10.15.3

Comment: I figured out what the issue was.  My package.xml referenced a WorkflowRule and WorkflowFieldUpdate that were not included as meta data.

Comment: @MichaelSobczak, i think mine also related to work flow, got same issue even when i try to download(retrieve) case workflow file from org browser meta data.Starting SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org

09:38:43.13 sfdx force:source:retrieve --sourcepath c:\XXXX\SFDX\Local\force-app\main\default\workflows\Case.workflow-meta.xml
ERROR running force:source:retrieve:  Maximum call stack size exceeded